# Help! image appearing twice on product page

Tags: magento-1.9, product-images, image, image-upload, help-wanted

we have had our website developed with an offshore team located in India and it to see I would be putting it lightly if I said it has been frustrating.

I have no idea about coding and pretty much self taught when it comes to the magento admin side of things. We are using magento 1.9 which I hear is pretty old school... is that right?

Any how... when we create a new product and upload the product image it seems to duplicate. See image below. Is this something I can fix myself without having to code anything? can it be fixed in magento admin at all? Any help is much appreciated!

Thanks
 [image]

Answer (score 1):

The Issue may occured due to following 2 reasons.

1. JS Errors on PDP page
2. HTML element is duplicated in phtml file

**Case 1:**

The default magento product details page will show the main image with the option of zoom and zoom container will be hidden by default. Whenever customer mouse over the main image, the zoom image will appear in the mirror glass.

I hope, In your case, it may have some JavaScript error in product details page which is breaking the zoom container and displaying the zoom image also.

You can check whether any JS errors are reported on PDP page at browser developer tool.

Chrome Browser > Press F12 > Developer window will open > Check the console tab which will list down the errors if any.

If you found any errors means, you have to fix all the issue by the help of developer.

**Case 2:**

1. You have open the respective phtml page which is responsible to render the image content and check whether any specific html elements are duplicated.
2. If so, please remove the duplicated content and keep only one set of html elements.
3. Please check the PDP page in browser once you saved the page in editor.

I hope, It may give you some clarity on the issue.